# How can I define an array of objects using Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Can someone give me some advice. I have an array of objects here:

```
contentOrderBy = [
    { id: 0, name: 'CId', key: 'contentId' },
    { id: 1, name: 'Modified By', key: 'modifiedBy' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Modified Date', key: 'modified' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Status', key: 'contentStatusId' },
];
```

What I would like to do is to find how I can define this in Typescript.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not fully sure what do you mean by:

> What I would like to do is to find how I can define this in Typescript.

But one option is to introduce the `interface` and declare variable as array of such objects:

```
interface IMyEntity {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    key: string;    
}

var contentOrderBy = [
    { id: 0, name: 'CId', key: 'contentId' },
    { id: 1, name: 'Modified By', key: 'modifiedBy' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Modified Date', key: 'modified' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Status', key: 'contentStatusId' },
];

// finally here we have declaration of the array
// which contains the items of specified type/interface
// and we can later work with them "fully-typed"
var myContent : IMyEntity[] = contentOrderBy;

alert(myContent[0].name);
```

Check it [in action here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=interface%20IMyEntity%20%7B%0A%09id%3A%20number%3B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%09key%3A%20string%3B%09%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20contentOrderBy%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%200%2C%20name%3A%20'CId'%2C%20key%3A%20'contentId'%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%201%2C%20name%3A%20'Modified%20By'%2C%20key%3A%20'modifiedBy'%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%202%2C%20name%3A%20'Modified%20Date'%2C%20key%3A%20'modified'%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%203%2C%20name%3A%20'Status'%2C%20key%3A%20'contentStatusId'%20%7D%2C%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Avar%20myContent%20%3A%20IMyEntity%5B%5D%20%3D%20contentOrderBy%3B%0A%0Aalert(myContent%5B0%5D.name)%3B%0A%0A)

Comment: To be clear you can also define the type upon array creation.... `var contentOrderBy: IMyEntity[] = [ ... ];`

Answer (score 6):

To declare the array the following two syntaxes are valid, if you are looking for an option that avoids the use of an interface:

```
contentOrderBy: { id: number, name: string, key: string }[];
```

or

```
contentOrderBy: Array<{ id: number, name: string, key: string }>;
```

Then populate the array as in the OP's question.

**Since I found this question while searching for the correct way to define an array inside the object I will add that example also. In this example the 'key' property of the object is an array of strings.**

```
contentOrderBy: { id: number, name: string, key: string[] }[];
```

or

```
contentOrderBy: Array<{ id: number, name: string, key: Array<string> }>;
```

Comment: and how would you push things in this kind of an array. eg. var ct={id:item.id,name:item.name,key:item.key}; contentOrderBy.push(ct);

Answer (score 0):

You could try either of these. They are not giving me errors..

```
//Declare with default value
private _possessions: Array<Thing> = new Array<Thing>();
```

or

```
//declare
private _possessions: Array<Thing>;
constructor(){
//assign
     this._possessions = new Array<Thing>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var storesArray : Store[]  = [
  {
    app_category : "app_cat",
    app_id : "11",
    id : "12",
    name : "g1",
    target_audience: "tar_aud",
    type: "intune"
  },
  {
    app_category : "app_cat2",
    app_id : "112",
    id : "122",
    name : "g12",
    target_audience: "tar_aud2",
    type: "intune2"
  }]
```